# Is it possible to run two commands and deal with both outputs on same page

Tags: php, linux

I am running two linux commands with popen() in php. If I run 1, I can gather the output and process it fine. If I run two at the same time while funneling to the page with 2>&1, output gets jumbled. Is it possible to run two commands and deal with both outputs on same page?

I basically duplicated the bottom code for each command

```
$handle = popen ("-some long command 2>&1");

while (false !== ($char = fgetc($handle)))
{
  if ($char == "\r")
  {
    // You could now parse the $line for status information.
$line= "$line\n";
if (preg_match("/Duration: (.*?),/", $line, $matches)){
//do stuff

}

$line = "";
} else {
$line .= $char;
}
ob_flush();
flush();
}
pclose ($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) allows multiple, asynchronous commands execution; you would get the output through the *stdout* pipe.

PS: never duplicate code; use functions instead!

Comment: I am having trouble duplicating the realtime process I have shown above. How would you duplicate what I have done above. The proc_open seems to just deliver the output at the end.

Comment: nvm I got it to work. It is coming out of stderr though. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Happened to me before... I guess it depends on how the command handles output.